# How to extract column values from a record

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

Which function of JdbcTemplate to use to extract the column values from a record which is returned by the SQL in a spring MVC Web Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options available, it depends on the context of the your code and the data you're retrieving. Have a look at the [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) API, in particular the `query` methods. In most cases you will need to define either a `RowMapper` or `ResultSetExtractor` for the model you're populating.